# JS Closures - What is the value of x?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

This is a thought exercise. I'm not doing anything with this code and the purpose is to better understand how closures work.

Thought Process:

1. x === 10 in global scope.
2. outer() function is called.
3. x === 20 in the global scope and local scope.
4. inner() function is called.
5. right side of 'var x' is expressed.
6. In x + 20, because x is not defined in local scope, it searches outer scope and finds x === 20.
7. var x = 20 + 20.
8. var x === 40.
9. return x.
10. result === 40.

However, the answer is 20. Why is this?

```
var x = 10;

function outer () {
  x = 20;
  function inner () {
    var x = x + 20;
    return x;
  }
  inner();
}

outer();

var result = x;
```

Comment: `6. In x + 20, because x is not defined in local scope, it searches outer scope` This is false.

Comment: @vol7ron `var`s are hoisted - it *does* exist locally (with a value of `undefined`) when the attempted assignment occurs.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're exactly right.  let me be an example of why you shouldn't get online after happy hour! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `inner()` function is called, the first thing that happens is `var x`.

This means the JavaScript interpreter first creates a variable named `x` to which it assigns `undefined`.

Then it runs the assignment expression `x + 20`, which is equivalent to `undefined + 20` which is `NaN`.

Your variable `result` has nothing to do with your `inner()` function as you have a local variable (because of that `var x`) and you ignore the returned result.

In other words, your code is equivalent to just this:

```
var x = 10;

function outer () {
  x = 20;
}

outer();

var result = x;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a great explanation and it cleared up any confusion that I had. Not only did you clear up my ideas on the value of result, I was able to understand the value of x in the inner function!

Comment: My pleasure. Also, the `var` keyword could appear anywhere in the function and it would still be taken in account at the time you enter the function. I'm not sure how it's handled in ES6+. They say it's scoped so it should only change the variable within block scope instead of the entire function. I haven't tested that theory, though.

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner function defined a local var x which will hide the global variable outside. And the outer function uses the global variable x and assign it to 20. Obviously, the global x is 20. Javascript will define every local variable before you call the function in the prototype chain.

```
var x = 10;
function outer () {
  x = 20;
  function inner () {
    alert(x); // alert undefined
    var x = x + 20;
    return x;
  }
  inner();
}
outer();
var result = x;
```